# -sh /usr/local/sbin/wpa_supplicant no such file or directory

Tags: yocto, zynq, wpa, petalinux

I have built the TI wilink utilities which then I have integrated in my rootfs. This done using petalinux 2016.4 and have created a install template app in yocto build to copy all the tools and libraries in the rootfs.
When I bring up the BOOT.bin and image.ub, I see the files and libraries but when I try to run for example wpa_supplicant it does not work
even `wpa_supplicant -h` wont work.
It shows me error:

> -sh: /usr/local/sbin/wpa_supplicant: no such file or directory.

The file is present and also has executable permissions. 
Do you have any idea why it is not able to run ?
Thanks

Comment: what is the output of  # file /usr/local/sbin/wpa_supplicant

Comment: You may consider upgrading your version of Petalinux.  The Wilink drivers are now part of the mainline Linux kernel and no longer need to be cross-compiled: https://e2e.ti.com/blogs_/b/process/archive/2015/06/09/wilink-8-drivers-now-available-in-mainline-linux

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Typically, this means that executable file is built for the wrong architecture, i.e. there is a mismatch between the environment where are you running and environment for which you are building. This is how you can make sure they do match or not (execute on target):

```
# file  /usr/local/sbin/wpa_supplicant
...

# uname -m 
...
```

If you see mismatch, then it all boils down to how are you building TI wilink.